# Why did companions have such high social standing?

Tags: firefly

I've been watching *Firefly*. While I've been enjoying the show, the one thing I haven't been able to quite figure out is why companions have such high social standing. They are admittedly quite "posh", but what about them makes them so well received among the upper class?

Comment: Out-of-universe answer: Because Joss Whedon was told by the producers to add a space prostitute to his concept, and being a rampant feminist, he invented the highest-class prostitute he could think of. (Also, subverting tropes is his particular hobby-horse.)

Comment: @KilianFoth Someone really went on record saying that it was mandatory to include a sex worker on the ship? That seems like a bizarre requirement...

Comment: @KilianFoth I find it FAR more likely that, as stated in universe, it was used by the writers as a way to keep the main characters "shadier", yet still provide them with a means of getting into higher-class planets/situations. Inara was definitely empowered, and the life that she chose was her own choosing, something that anyone who cares for women's rights should applaud. I find your comment rather juvenile and misogynist.

Answer (score 85, accepted):

### They're much more than just prostitutes.

From the [Firefly Wikia](http://firefly.wikia.com/wiki/Companion%27s_Guild):

> Registered Companions are culturally well-educated with training in a number of areas, including psychology, music, fencing, and languages, as well as unarmed martial arts. On the "core" planets, Companions were typically trained from a very young age.

This is **not unrealistic**: compare with the real-life [oiran](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oiran), Japanese courtesans some of whom had fairly high status in society, doubtless much more than a bandit, smuggler, and 'petty thief' such as Malcolm Reynolds would have had:

> Compared to yūjo (prostitutes), whose primary attraction was their sexual favors, courtesans were first and foremost entertainers. In order to become an oiran, a woman had to be educated in a range of skills, including the traditional arts of sadō (Japanese tea ceremony), ikebana (flower arranging), and calligraphy. Oiran also learned to play the koto, shakuhachi, tsuzumi (hand drum), and shamisen. Clients also expected them to be well-read and able to converse and write with wit and elegance.
>
> Within the pleasure quarters, courtesans' prestige was based on their beauty, character, education, and artistic ability, rather than their birth.
>
> The highest rank of courtesan was the tayū (太夫?), followed by the kōshi (格子?). Unlike a common prostitute, the tayū had sufficient prestige to refuse clients. Her high status also made a tayū extremely pricey—a tayū's fee for one evening was between one ryo and one ryo three bu, well beyond a laborer's monthly wage and comparable to a shop assistant's annual salary.

Given the similarities between the above description of oiran and some of what Inara tells us about Companions - even down to specifics such as the tea ceremony - it seems likely that Joss Whedon consciously based the Companion system on the real-life oiran. But I haven't yet found anything canonical to confirm this, so I've [asked a question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/141812/31394) about it to find out.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense! I didn't know about the oiran, but the concept is so similar it seems obvious. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: I like how you only explain what the tsuzumi is, leaving the other 3 instruments unexplained.

Comment: @Axelrod Don't blame me, blame Wikipedia!

Comment: Not just Japan. The word courtesan itself came from [Medieval society](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Courtesan), and indicated a woman who was intelligent, talented, and of a high enough social standing to be an accepted presence in "court", in addition to her, er, "companion" duties. The vast majority of the population (of either gender) would not be welcome at that level.

Comment: @Axelrod: I think the koto (stringed instrument) and shakuhachi (flute) are slightly better known than the tsuzumi and shamisen - at least, I knew what they were. Doesn't help with the shamisen though. Feel free to edit wikipedia to add the appropriate links ...

Comment: @BenBolker Shamisen is the only one of those four words that sounds vaguely familiar to me, and I'm still not sure exactly what it is.

Comment: [koto](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Koto_(instrument)), [shakuhachi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shakuhachi), [shamisen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shamisen), [tsuzumi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tsuzumi) (all wikipedia links)

Comment: Not to mention hetairas in ancient greece who were similar in many ways to Japanese courtesans.

Comment: @BenBolker I can think of at least one reason the Koto might be known in western culture. "bought a koto in kumomoto, traded it for an Elvis photo"

Comment: @Pharap nice. I assume you're referring to [this](https://genius.com/Daphne-and-celeste-i-love-your-sushi-lyrics) (I have to say I've never heard it, nor heard of Daphne and Celeste before ...)

Comment: @BenBolker Indeed I am. They were somewhat well known in certain places (mainly New Zealand) for a few months around the turn of the millenium, but I'm sure the song itself has been used one or two times in backing tracks to various films and series.

Answer (score 31):

While there is no doubt that companions are sex-workers they are much more than that.

From [**Wikipedia**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Firefly_characters#Inara_Serra) (re Inara)

> ... Companion, a high-society courtesan licensed by the Union of Allied Planets (the "Alliance").
>
> In Alliance society, Companions are **part of the social elite**, often accompanying the wealthy and powerful. **There is considerable ritual and ceremony surrounding their services, which appear to extend beyond sex to nurturing psychological, spiritual, physical, and emotional well being.**
>
> Companions do not view themselves as prostitutes and are insulted by the suggestion.
>
> Companions choose their own customers, and to be chosen by one is considered a great honor and status symbol, as those chosen must be both wealthy enough to afford a Companion's often steep price and desirable enough to attract one

So, a companion is a highly skilled **legal** professional that has been through extensive training in the services they provide and, just like any other highly sought after professional, are welcomed accordingly.

***Note*** also that **they** choose who they will have as clients, not the other way around. **They imbue status on their clients** making them highly prized.